# Terminology for a set of functions formed from a basic set of functions and all their compositions?

Tags: functions, terminology

Let suppose I have a set $A$ and a set of functions $S$ from $A$ to itself. I can define a new set $S*$ that, intuitively, is the set of all functions formed by composing zero or more copies of functions from $S$. Formally:

- $id_A \in S*$
- For any $f \in S*$ and $g \in S$, the function $g \circ f$ is in $S*$.

Is there a standard  name for this set $S*$? I can call it the monoid generated by $S$, but it seems like there's probably a simpler name for it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called a [transformation monoid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_semigroup)  or composition  monoid. You can still include *generated by $S$* for clarity.